# Django - calling custom update behaviour when overriding its behavour

Tags: django, django-queryset

What I am trying to do is best described by example. Consider the following:

```
class QuerySetManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        result = self.model.QuerySet(self.model)
        try:
            result = result.filter(is_deleted=False)
        except FieldError:
            pass
        return result

class MyModel(model.Models):
    # core fields
    objects = QuerySetManager()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_model'

    class QuerySet(QuerySet):
        def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
           if something_special:
              # handle that special case
           else:
              # call custom update
```

In effect, I am trying to override the update method of QuerySet's superclass. If something special happens, I would like to implement update process myself, and otherwise - call the standard update method of the superclass.
Any help on what the correct syntax is?

**UPDATE**
Let me provide a bit detailed background.
I am using the pattern found [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/734/).
The entire architecture looks like this:

```
class DeleteMixin(models.Model):
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class QuerySetManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        result = self.model.QuerySet(self.model)
        try:
            result = result.filter(is_deleted=False)
        except FieldError:
            pass
        return result

class Sms(DeleteMixin):
   # core fields 
   objects = QuerySetManager()

   class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'sms'
   class QuerySet(QuerySet):
       def inbox(self, user):
           return self.filter(sms_type_id = 1)

       def outbox(self, user):
           return self.filter(sms_type_id = 2)
       def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
           if something_special:
              # handle that special case
           else:
              # the issue in question - call custom update
```

This architecture enables me to:

- exclude records with `is_deleted` field equal to 1 (for those tables where there is such field)
- use chainable filters like sms.objects.inbox().outbox()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enitrely clear what you are asking. IF you are trying to add a custom update method to a Queryset's superclass update method like this:

```
class MyQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
           ....

         super(MyQuerySet,self).update(*args,**kwargs)
```

if you are trying to override the save method in the model

```
class MyModel(model.Models):
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ...
        super(MyModel,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

### Update (pun intended)

The code sample I have posted above is correct. The QuerySet class definitely as an update method. as can be seen here:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L630

And if you have sub classed QuerySet correctly you will not get the error. But you haven't

```
class QuerySet(QuerySet):
```

This is incorrect.

Comment: I am trying to Queryset's superclass update method. Your proposal yields `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: I did not place correct tag spaces, so you probably misunderstood the example code snippet. Please see the updated question. I subclass the QuerySet

Comment: Well, seems like it is correct now. Also, I've added a bit more context in the code snippet to clarify the logic

Comment: Sorry, I am semi-experienced in Django) But I still can't see what's wrong? Is it the indentation or I am breaching class naming conventions ? Could you please submit the entire code snippet as it should be ?)

Comment: Sorry can't do that because it's not at all clear why you even have a subclass of QuerySet it doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: Secondly, when you subclass something you give the derived class a different name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133426/discussion-between-edgar-navasardyan-and-e4c5).

Answer (score -2):

Eventually, I got it work this way:

```
def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if something_special:
        # handle that special case
    else:
        super(self.model.QuerySet, self).update(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: this is basically my answer